# How to use Rails validates only if not a new user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I have the following in my user.rb:

```
validates :fname, :length => { :minimum => 1, :maximum => 100 }
validates :lname, :length => { :minimum => 1, :maximum => 100 }
```

How can I update this validations to only apply to existing users? I ask as I want to allow a user to signup without having to enter a fname or lname.

Ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
validates :fname, :length => { :minimum => 1, :maximum => 100 }, :unless => :new_record?
validates :fname, :length => { :minimum => 1, :maximum => 100 }, :unless => :new_record?
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `:on => :update`, to make the validation only apply when a record is updated (as opposed to `:on => :create`)